Conditional Distribution of $X - u$ Given $X > u$ for a GPD
I am asked to determine the conditional distribution of $X - u$ given $X > u$. Given that $X$ follows the Generalized Pareto Distribution (GPD) with the cumulative distribution function $H(x; \gamma, \sigma) = 1 - \left(1 + \gamma \frac{x}{\sigma}\right)^{-1/\gamma}$, , considering the case where $\gamma \neq 0$. We begin by applying Bayes' theorem as follows:
$$
P(X - u > y \mid X > u) = P(X > y + u \mid X > u) = \frac{P(X > u \mid X > y + u) \cdot P(X > y + u)}{P(X > u)}.
$$
Since $P(X > u \mid X > y + u) = 1$, this simplifies to:
$$
P(X - u > y \mid X > u) = \frac{P(X > y + u)}{P(X > u)} = \frac{H(y + u)}{H(u)} = \frac{\left(1 + \gamma \frac{y + u}{\sigma}\right)^{-1/\gamma}}{\left(1 + \gamma \frac{u}{\sigma}\right)^{-1/\gamma}} = \left(1 + \gamma \frac{y}{\sigma + \gamma u}\right)^{-1/\gamma}.
$$
Now, since we are interested in the conditional distribution $P(X - u \leq y \mid X > u)$, we find:
$$
P(X - u \leq y \mid X > u) = 1 - P(X - u > y \mid X > u) = 1 - \left(1 + \gamma \frac{y}{\sigma + \gamma u}\right)^{-1/\gamma}.
$$
Thus, the conditional distribution is:
$$
H(y; \gamma, \sigma + \gamma u).
$$
Is this correct? I'm asking because the proof in my book seems much more complicated.

It looks good to me (maybe the sign of $y$ can be discussed somewhere).

Thanks for your comment! Yes, I should emphasize that $y \geq 0$.
